# get the timestamp for the minimum/maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql

i am new in learning sql. how to create query to get the timestamp of a minimum value and the minimum value itself?
previously i managed to get the minimum value but not with its timestamp. with this query

```
SELECT min(score) as lowest 
FROM rank 
WHERE time >= CAST(CURDATE() AS DATE)
```

here is the table that i've created:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/9sMV8b4/aa.png]

(cannot attach image because of the reputation rule)

sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Note that rank is now a reserved word, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier, and please don't attach pictures where raw text would do just as well.

Comment: thank you for the advice, i'll replace the reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you either expect that there would be only a single record with the lowest score, or if there be ties, you don't care which record gets returned, then using `LIMIT` might be the easiest way to go here:

```
SELECT timestamp, score
FROM rank
WHERE time >= CAST(CURDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY score
LIMIT 1;
```

If you care about ties, and want to see all of them, then we can use a subquery:

```
SELECT timestamp, score
FROM rank
WHERE time >= CAST(CURDATE() AS DATE) AND
      score = (SELECT MIN(score) FROM rank WHERE time >= CAST(CURDATE() AS DATE));
```

Comment: it works! Thank you Tim, i really appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by following way.

Note: It only works if you want to get a single record at once

```
select score, time
FROM rank 
WHERE time >= CAST(CURDATE() AS DATE)
ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: have you executed your query? I don't understand how this answer can get 3 votes? and your answer is just copied answer of @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Yes, I've executed my query. Sorry, but it's not copied from other.

Comment: ha ha ha bro, nobody will believe you as @Tim's answer was posted 9 mins before your answer - and you know what your answer also give wrong output

Comment: the differences between Tim and Pinal answer is tim select the lowest score and pinal select the highest score. I appreciate both of your answer. Thank you